# Image, when resized turns blurry instead of being pixelated

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image

So I'm building simple UI and wanted to add pixel art to it.

I have this image in 20px x 20px, and when I resize it with looking glass or in any software, it just gets pixelated, which is fine:

http://prntscr.com/np1f02

However, when I add the image with  tag and set its width and height like:

```
<img src={helmetSlot} style={{width: 64, height: 64}}/>
```

It looks terribly blurry:
http://prntscr.com/np1flc

What is the cause of this? How can I prevent that?

SOLVED:
Used image-rendering: pixelated; css proeprty to fix it. Never knew about existance of this property

Answer (score 2):

image-rendering: pixelated;
Did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the height and width to be bigger than your source file. Why don't you export your pixel art at a higher resolution and then downres it.

Example: export it at 128px x 128px. Then displaying it at 64 x 64 should be no problem.

Comment: I still dont see why would it happen this way, I bought this pixel pack in 20x20, and resising each one by hand will be a pain in the butt. IMO it should get pixely when resized, not blurry

Comment: What's the file extension? Did the pack come with SVGs?